# on click body not div jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi friends I want to close sidenav bar which has class name `.menu-wrap` when user click on body except '.menu-wrap'. I have tried to figure out the solution but as per my code when I click on '.menu-wrap' its works fine but if click on child elements of  `.menu-wrap` then my code fails. Please check my code below

**jQuery**

```
$('html, body').on('click', function(e){

      if ($(e.target).hasClass('menu-wrap') || $(e.target).parent('div[data-rel="side-menu"]').hasClass('menu-wrap')) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $('.menu-wrap').hide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution

**jQuery**

```
$('html, body').on('click', function(e){

      if ($(e.target).parent('menu-wrap').length) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $('.menu-wrap').hide();
      }
    });
```